# selenium - actions class- multiple actions not working

Tags: selenium, action

I am trying to  select third level sub-menu items on below website. Code gets executed without any errors here however click action is not performed on the final sub-menu item.

Website: https://www.bigbasket.com/

Menu items: `Shop By Category -> Personal Care -> Ayurvedic`

I am running this script on chrome browser. I tried to select second level menu item however third level menu item is not getting selected. Btw with the help of java script executor I am able to do the same action successfully.

```
Actions builder= new Actions(driver);

Action act=builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[1]/a")))             
                .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/cl/personal-care/?nc=nb']")))
                .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/pc/personal-care/ayurvedic-non-food/?nc=nb']")))

.click()
.build();

//perform() method when executing the Action object we designed above

act.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.build().perform()` after every action because all the "findElement" methods run at the start of a new Action. And executing "perform()" makes them search again

Comment: did not resolve the issue..it just navigates as earlier but click action is not simulated.  https://www.bigbasket.com/  is the sample website if you want to give it a try  for menu1-->menu2-->menu3

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

Actions builder= new Actions(driver);

```
Action act=builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[1]/a")))
.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/cl/personal-care/?nc=nb']"))) .click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/pc/personal-care/ayurvedic-non-food/?nc=nb']")))

.build();

act.perform();
```

Comment: did not resolve the issue..it just navigates as earlier but click action is not simulated.  https://www.bigbasket.com/  is the sample website if you want to give it a try  for menu1-->menu2-->menu3